# Conditional formatting in Access won't work using Expression

Tags: vba, ms-access, report, expression, conditional-formatting

I have a report based on a query which is a simple select statement. I am trying to create conditional formatting so that if `(Date()-[Datefield]) >= 5`, the entire row will be highlighted in red.

I am doing it using the Gui as I'm not that familiar with VBA. I am following the documentation to the letter but nothing happens when I apply the rule.

The only way I managed to get conditional formatting to work was on cell level using the "Field Value is" option.

If I try using an expression on a single field `(IsNull([Telephone])`, nothing happens. I've tried deleting both the query and the report and also re-installing MS Office but nothing changes.

Any ideas what could be wrong? It sort of worked at some point yesterday and then stopped but since then I've tried reinstalling Office and also creating a new DB from scratch. Nothing seems to make any difference.

I'm willing to try configuring it via VBA so I can at least debug it but I'd need somewhere to start...

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot make conditional formatting on rows, only on individual controls, so you will have to repeat the same process on each control you want the conditional formatting to apply.

Comment: According to Microsoft, you can: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg508986(v=office.14).aspx However on my DB I can't get any expression to work - even if it is for a single field.

Comment: yes, you're right. I was testing on a database where one of the fields cannot be formated.

Comment: in what cases does that happen, i.e. a field cannot be formatted?

Comment: I used an old database with an OLE object.

Comment: Solved the problem by changing the system locale on my workstation to Bulgarian which is apparently a necessity when some of your DB objects have names in Bulgarian (Cyrillic)...

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by changing the system locale on my workstation to Bulgarian which is apparently a necessity when some of your DB objects have names in Bulgarian (Cyrillic)...